# How can I find detailed Sony Exif codes in a format that I can use

Tags: metadata, sony

**Summary**

Where can I find Exif codes of the type shown below that cover all features of my cameras?
(I have mainly Sony cameras but a more general resource would be welcome).

---

I have too many Sony cameras :-).
I recently bought a Sony A7RIV. It further complicates my requirement.   I wish to display selected camera parameters on screen when editing photos, or to search and subset photos based on specific Exif codes.

I am mostly using Irfanview (!) for this task but the question is not editor specific

I am aware of many codes.
Some are available via the Irfanview help files and a few others I have obtained from other sources. Web searches mostly turn up tables with obscure codes that seem t have no relationship to the EXIF addresses.

The A7RIV has many additional codes that I wish to utilise.
e.g.:

- JPG quality: Extra Fine/Fine/Standard.
- APSC JPEG resolution: 26/15/6 Mp

As examples only of the sort of information and codes I am aware of:

```
$m       megapixels  
$W  image pixel width    
$H  image pixel height  
$E45094  Lens stabilisation on/off  
$E34855  ISO   
$E33437  Aperture  
$E33434  Shutter speed ...
```

Many more ...

**QUESTION:**  Where can I find Exif codes of the type shown above that cover all features of my cameras?
or
How can I derive this information?

Comment: I would highly suggest parsing `exiftool -json` output or using the `Image::Exiftool` or `exiv2` libraries directly, any of which will let you access things by *name*, rather than just raiding them for a list of magic numbers.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks - I'll see if I can get Irfanview to accept names other than thos it names :-). eg $H is image pixel height. The magic numbers that I use are decimal addresses that I have garnered from various sources.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the codes in the [CIPA Exif v2.3 standard](https://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf).

Sony tags are also listed in [exiftool's documentation](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Sony.html).

[Exiv2 tool's documentation](https://exiv2.org/tags.html) also list tags.

Comment: Thanks - those helped. Still not a complete fix. Some of the tags are in a form that I do not know how to translate into EXIF loctions. More anon, probbly. I will plaay.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your data isn't Sony specific. The size (width/height/megapixel) is part of the JPEG data (not even the EXIF).

JPEG quality as defined by Sony (Extra Fine/Fine/Standard) is a combination of JPEG quality and possibly chroma subsampling, that are also part of the JPEG data.

Comment: The quality is more likely part of the [Sony MakerNotes](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Sony.html)